# replace a text from emacs buffer to insert it vertically with emacs lisp script

Tags: elisp

I just found this post with vim (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704130/can-i-transpose-a-file-in-vim) and i just wanted to do the same thing with elisp by creating a little script to reordenate all the characters from a buffer text into a vertical position.

As the post said, the original buffer might be:

```
THE DAY WAS LONG 
THE WAY WAS FAST
```

and it would become:

```
TT
HH
EE

DW
AA
YY

WW
AA
SS

LF
OA
NS
GT
```

I write this little emacs script to first read each buffer lines in a list (removing spaces), and after using a zip function to transpose each characters between lists, and at the end iterate my list to print it in x columns.

```
(require 'subr-x)
(defun read-buffer-lines (buf)
  (let ((lines '()))
    (with-current-buffer buf
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (while (not (eobp))
          (if (not (string-equal "" (buffer-substring (point) (point-at-eol))))
              (push
               (delete " " (delete "" (split-string
                                       (string-trim (buffer-substring (point) (point-at-eol)))
                                       "")))
                  lines)
              )
            (beginning-of-line 2))
        (erase-buffer) ;; clean buffer
        (nreverse lines)
        ))))



(defun zip_list (lst)
  (let ((res))
    (while (-none? 'null lst)
      (setq res (cons (mapcar 'car lst) res))
      (setq lst (mapcar 'cdr lst)))
    (nreverse res)
    ))


(let* ((buf "*scratch*")
       (a (zip_list (read-buffer-lines buf))))
  (with-current-buffer buf
    (while a
      (progn
        (insert (mapconcat 'identity (car a) ""))
        (newline)
        (setq a (cdr a))))))
```

Comment: Why would you save excursion and erase buffer? :) Where would Emacs have to put the mouse after the buffer is erased? Other than that: there's an easier way to split the contents of the buffer into lines: `(split-string (buffer-string) "\n")`. I wouldn't use a list of list to model a matrix (which you want to transpose). A vector of vectors would've made the task a lot easier.

Comment: agree. good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few general points about your code:

1. `(while condition &body)` form already treats `&body` as an implicit `progn`. There's no reason to wrap it in a `progn`.
2. `insert` accepts multiple arguments.  So, you could write `(insert (mapconcat ...) "\n")` instead of calling `(insert ...)` followed by `(newline)`.
3. Traditionally, Lisp functions use `-` when the name of the function consists of multiple words, so, it would be better to call `zip-list`, not `zip_list`.
4. `(let (res) ...)` is exactly the same as `(let ((res)) ...)` but shorter.
5. `(setq ...)` can handle multiple assignments, they are executed in order they are written, so `(setq a b c a)` will assign `b` to `c`.  No reason to write `(setq a b) (setq c a)`.
6. `split-string` has argument `OMIT-NULLS` that controls whether empty strings are included in the results.  It would be better to rely on this argument than to post-process the results.
7. As mentioned in the comments, there's an easier, more idiomatic way to obtain all lines of text from the buffer: `(split-string (buffer-string) "\n")`.

Finally, unless only for the sake of an exercise in writing the `zip-list` function, the transpose operation calls for something like vector, not a list.  Below is a possible alternative which uses vectors to perform this operation:

```lisp
(defun wvxvw/transpose-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((lines (split-string (buffer-string) "\n"))
         (max-length
          (cl-loop for line in lines
                   maximize (max (length line))))
         (src (cl-coerce lines 'vector))
         (dst (cl-loop with matrix = (make-vector max-length nil)
                       with len = (length src)
                       for i below max-length do
                       (aset matrix i (make-vector len ?\ ))
                       finally (cl-return matrix))))
    (cl-loop for i upfrom 0
             for line across src do
             (cl-loop for j upfrom 0
                      for c across line do
                      (aset (aref dst j) i c)))
    (erase-buffer)
    (cl-loop for line across dst do
             (insert (cl-coerce line 'string) "\n"))))
```

Comment: nice work ! i just tried it and it work like a charm ! thank you for all your suggestions. there are very useful for me.